# which operator is this "?." in next-auth example?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

In [next-auth-jwt-callback](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) there's an example code which uses "?." operator. I don't know which operator is this. I tried this operator in `node.js` but it raised `Syntax Error`.

```
  async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
    if (account?.accessToken) {
      token.accessToken = account.accessToken
    }
    return token
  }
```

Comment: [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), in your case it might be not available**

Since it's only available on nodejs version 14 and above. You can find the list of browsers supporting optional chaining in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility).

You can also enable optional using `--harmony` flag

Comment: Does it help to answer your question? @Ishan Bassi